# SQL Server stored procedure dynamic Where condition in temporary table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using ASP.NET and a SQL Server database.

I have options to search values from gridview base on some criteria. The criteria are mostly independent from each other.

For example:

```
"where ProductType = " + Convert.ToInt32(recordType.persoRecord) + 
" and AccountNumber like '%" + SearchValue + "%'";
```

or

```
"where fileid=" + File_ID + ShowSearch + 
" and lower(j.CardHolderName) like '%" + SearchValue.Trim().ToLower() + "%'
```

There are a lot of options to search by user. I have millions of rows of data in this table, in order to fetch the data and bind it fast to gridview, I have created a stored procedure.

It works fine for fetching and binding but for searching, it's hard to manage. Due to I don't have much time, i want to configure the stored procedure to 'if there's a searching' fetch the searched data only.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetJobsGrid]
    (@FileID varchar(50),
     @PageIndex int = 1,
     @PageSize int = 1,
     @DynamicQuery  NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @SearchFlag bit,
     @RecordCount int output)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SearchQuerySQL as nvarchar(MAX)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select ROW_NUMBER()OVER (
         order by j.creationdate asc,
                            j.id desc
    ) AS RowNumber
    ,  j.id as 'Serial #', j.jobname as 'File Record Name', 
                                j.RecordNumber as 'Record Number',i.issuername as'Issuer Name',p.ProductName as 'Product Name',p.productNumber as 'Product Number', 
                                (j.AccountNumber) as AccountNumber ,j.CardHolderName as 'Card Holder Name', j.CardholdersBranchName as 'Card Holder Branch Name', 
                                j.ShipmentBranchName as 'Shipment Branch Name', j.EmbossingCardholderName as 'Embossing Card Holder Name', j.MaskedPAN as 'PAN',
                                j.creationdate as 'File Record Creation Date', j.status as 'File Record Status', j.chipdatastatuserror as 'ChipDataStatus Erro', 
                                j.chipdatastatuserrormessage as 'Error Message', j.chipdatastatus as 'Data Prepared',j.isduplicaterecord as 'isduplicate',j.isduplicatefromsamefile as 'IsDuplicateFromSameFile',
                                j.validationerrors , j.isworkordercreatedForCard,j.isworkordercreatedForPin,j.isworkordercreatedForCarrier,j.PersoMachineId,j.PinMachineId,j.CarrierMachineId
                                INTO #Results
                                FROM  jobs j join issuer i on j.issuerid=i.id join Product p on p.id=j.productid WHERE fileid = @FileID

        IF(@SearchFlag = 1)
            begin
                select @SearchQuerySQL = 'SELECT ' + @RecordCount + ' = COUNT(*) FROM #Results ' + @DynamicQuery 

                EXEC(@SearchQuerySQL)

                select @SearchQuerySQL = 'SELECT * FROM #Results ' + @DynamicQuery + ' and RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1'

                EXEC(@SearchQuerySQL)

            end
        ELSE
            begin
                SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
                FROM #Results

                SELECT * FROM #Results
                WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1
            end

    DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

When the `SearchFlag` is set to true from ASP.NET, I want to fetch only searched value. `@DynamicQuery` set from asp for example:

```
WHERE AccountNumber LIKE '%" + SearchValue + "%'"
```

or with many different case.

When I run this stored procedure as in the above, I get an exception:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'select ' to data type int

Regards

Comment: This feels like an XY problem Storing `WHERE` clauses in a table is something you should never need to do. It also opens up a big whole for injection problems. The above is also already suffering massively from injection as well, especially with statements like `select @SearchQuerySQL = 'SELECT * FROM #Results ' + @DynamicQuery + ' and ...'`. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: There are lots of ways to do dynamic search conditions, not all of them good. Erland Sommarskog has a nice [article](http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) on all the ways you can do this, with pros and cons. As a general rule, if you're going to generate *any* logic of a query client-side (that is, not just a list of values) you are almost always better off generating *all* of it client-side, as it's both more honest about the injection risk and easier to actually manage and secure in terms of escaping. But as the linked article explains, you often don't need dynamic SQL at all.

Answer (score 0):

To make the stored procedure use your dynamic where statement, it is better to use `sp_executesql`

example:

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
N'select * from Employees where Id = @param1', 
N'@param1 int'
,@param1 = 1
```

for more information about dynamic query refer to the following site

[SQL Server Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment but you need to understand why the error occurs to fix it. You have this snippet in your code

```
select @SearchQuerySQL = 'SELECT ' + @RecordCount +
```

First, if you intend to assign a scalar value (e.g., *@SearchQuerySQL*) then you should use SET, not SELECT. That's another topic you can research at your leisure.  The assignment expression that follows is where you intended to do string concatenation. Unfortunately, the interpretation of the plus sign operator varies according to datatypes involved.

What happens when the database engine encounters an operator that involves 2 different datatypes. Like any other language, one (or both) must be converted to the same type in order to perform the expressed operation. How does the engine do that? There are rules for [datatype precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). In this case, your int parameter has higher precedence and so those strings in that expression are converted to int. That fails with the error that you encountered.

If you want to write dynamic sql, you need to have an advanced understanding of tsql. You should also consider searching the internet first before trying to reinvent the wheel. Maybe Aaron's article on [dynamic pagination](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch) might help - but it might be a bit much for you at this point.

And while you're mucking about with things, add some comments within the procedure declaration about the usage you intend to support. No one should have to read your code to understand what it does and how it should be used.

Comment: Thank you @SMor for suggesting useful articles and advices. I will take in consider.